# awk - extract value infront of "somestring:"

Tags: awk, scripting

I'm creating a script that will get the UUID of inserted drive realtime using

```bsh
udiskctl monitor
```

these are some of stdout lines

```bsh
HintPartitionable:          true
HintSymbolicIconName:       
HintSystem:                 false
Id:                         by-uuid-EXTERNALLABEL
IdLabel:                    
IdType:                     vfat
IdUUID:                     EXTERNALLABEL
IdUsage:                    filesystem
IdVersion:                  FAT32
```

So I want to get the string in front of `idUUID:`

Expected Output:

```bsh
EXTERNALLABEL
```

Anyone have any idea then please suggest?

Comment: I'm sure there's a duplicates on U&L (or SO)

Comment: "In front of" ??? That would normally mean "to the left of". But your expected output is after (to the right of) the tag. Try: awk '/IdUUID/ { print $2 }'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a frequent question and there are answers on how to do this already, but you can use `awk` to do this:

```
udiskctl monitor | awk '{if (match($0,"^[[:space:]]*IdUUID:[[:space:]]*([[:print:]]+)",a)) print a[1]}'
```

or, even shorter as suggested by @Archemar

```
udiskctl monitor | awk '/^[[:space:]]*IdUUID:/ {print $2}'
```

or, more robust as suggested by @Ed Morton:

```
udiskctl monitor | awk '$1=="IdUUID:"{print $2}'
```

And or course, good old `sed`:

```
udiskctl monitor | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*IdUUID:[[:space:]]*//;t;d'
```

Comment: `udiskctl monitor | awk '/idUUID/ { print $2}' ` also work.

Comment: @Archemar `/^IdUUID:/` to be more sure to find the correct string.

Comment: Sorry for not researching enough, but thank you. It works like a charm!

Comment: @undefinedhax It's ok, it was a nice little exercise ..

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is:

```
$ awk '$1=="IdUUID:"{print $2}' file
EXTERNALLABEL
```

The currently accepted answer is unnecessarily and incorrectly treating the string you want to search for as if it were a regexp and so that approach would fail if your string contained regexp metacharacters.

Answer (score 0):

> Copyright James Daniel Marrs Ritchey. This material was created for submission at '[awk - extract value infront of "somestring:"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/553345/awk-extract-value-infront-of-somestring)' under the terms of the cc by-sa 4.0 (https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/legalcode), but can also be alternatively obtained from 'https://snippetly.blogspot.com/2019/12/extracting-value.html' under the terms of any of the following licenses: Comprehensible Open License 3.0 (https://jamesdanielmarrsritchey.blogspot.com/2019/06/comprehensible-open-license-30.html), MIT (https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT).

Alternatively to Awk, using PHP you can extract the value portion of the string by breaking the output into an array using line breaks as the delimiter. Then break each array value into another array using the colon as the delimiter. Next trim the whitespace from the beginning and end of each value. Lastly perform a check to see if it's the entry you want, and if it is echo the value.

```
<?php

$output = <<<'EOT'

Item1:          Value1

Item2:                     Value2

Item3:                     Value3

Item4:                  Value4

EOT;

$data = explode("\n", $output);

foreach ($data as $item){

    $result = FALSE;

    $value = explode(':', $item);

    if (trim($value[0]) === 'Item3'){

        echo trim($value[1]) . "\n";

        exit(0);

    }

}

echo "Value not found.\n";

exit(1);

?>
```